# CSS > Psuedo Elements > SVG > Can we reference an SVG group in the html?

Tags: html, css, svg, pseudo-element

Using the content or background attribute for a pseudo element (eg `::before` or `::after`), we can reference an external SVG file with `url('external.svg')` and can also insert directly the svg code `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>...</svg>)`.

But if we have the SVG already defined as a group in the html, can we reference as that in a pseudo element?

For example, in html like so:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <g id="SVG">
      <path d="M50,5 50,95 M25,75 50,95 75,75" style="stroke:#337ab7; stroke-width: 5; stroke-linecap: round; fill:none;"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

I tried the following and some variants, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
class::after {
  content: url('#SVG');
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Acknowledging that I am not the sharpest tool in the shed, I thought I would ask if anyone here knows whether this can be done and, if so, how.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate SVG elements (to change their height, color, or whatever), I suggest you take a look at Fabric.js.

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="c" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="57.08px" height="74.223px" viewBox="0 0 57.08 74.223" 
  enable-background="new 0 0 57.08 74.223" xml:space="preserve">
  <path d="M50,5 50,95 M25,75 50,95 75,75" style="stroke:#337ab7; 
  stroke-width: 5; stroke-linecap: round; fill:none;"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg{
  display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var svgEl = document.body.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svgEl);
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
var path = fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgStr, function(objects, options) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  obj.scaleToHeight(20)
    .set({
      left: canvas.width / 2,
      top: canvas.height / 2
    })
    .setCoords();

  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});
```

You can preview it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGXzJM

Original source: http://codepen.io/wadeharrell/pen/iebdw